# Batch Rename DIrectory Using Pattern Matches

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed, mp3

I would like to change this directory structure to the one following it. Although another directory batch rename question exists, this one is quite different.

```
l
'001. Aretha Franklin - Respect.mp3'*
'002. Ben E. King - Stand by Me.mp3'*
'003. Sam & Dave - Soul Man.mp3'*
'090. Archie Bell & The Drells; The Drells - Tighten Up, Pt. 1.mp3'*
```

```
for i in *.mp3; do echo $i | sed -E 's/([0-9]{3}. )(.*) *( - )(.*) *(.mp3)/\4\3\2\5/'; done;
```

```
Respect - Aretha Franklin.mp3
Stand by Me - Ben E. King.mp3
Soul Man - Sam & Dave.mp3
Tighten Up, Pt. 1 - Archie Bell & The Drells; The Drells.mp3
```

If I try to use the in-place option, I get this, with and without an input file:

```
for i in *.mp3; do echo $i | sed -iE 's/([0-9]{3}. )(.*) *( - )(.*) *(.mp3)/\4\3\2\5/'; done;
sed: -e expression #1, char 47: invalid reference \5 on `s' command's RHS
```

etc.

```
for i in *.mp3; do echo $i | sed -iE 's/([0-9]{3}. )(.*) *( - )(.*) *(.mp3)/\4\3\2\5/'<$i; done;
bash: $i: ambiguous redirect
```

etc.

```
for i in *.mp3; do echo $i | sed -Ei 's/([0-9]{3}. )(.*) *( - )(.*) *(.mp3)/\4\3\2\5/'; done;
sed: no input files
```

etc.

```
for i in *.mp3; do echo $i | sed -Ei 's/([0-9]{3}. )(.*) *( - )(.*) *(.mp3)/\4\3\2\5/' <$i; done;
bash: $i: ambiguous redirect
```

etc.

Back in the 1970s, I was able to edit the directory directly in Unix, as the directory listing itself is a file. I don't seem to be able to do that today.

vi . gives a blank screen filled with the normal empty file entries, and the bottom line shows this:

```
"." is a directory
```

while

```
ed .

Is a directory
```

How do I modify a directory listing in bulk today?  As you can see, I finally do have my expressions properly worked out, at least in sed. If there's a problem with them, too, please let me know. I am most grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
echo $i | sed ...
```

sed is operating on a *stream of bytes* read from the standard input stream, rather than on the file's directory entry - so editing "in place" makes no sense.

In addition, GNU sed treats an argument after `-i` as an optional backup suffix, so that when you write `sed -iE`, the `E` is no longer parsed as a flag indicating Extended Regular Expression syntax - which breaks your capture grouping.

If you want to rename files by manipulating their names using sed, you'd need to capture the resulting standard output stream in a *command substitution* and pass the result as a destination argument to the `mv` command ex.:

```
for i in *.mp3; do mv -- "$i" "$(echo "$i" | sed -E 's/pattern/replacement/')"; done
```

or

```
for i in *.mp3; do mv -- "$i" "$(sed -E 's/pattern/replacement/' <<< "$i")"; done
```

if you want to use shell redirection rather than piping to supply standard input to sed. Note that a single command cannot accept standard input from both a pipe and a redirection - that's an "ambiguous redirect".

(In the 1970s, you'd have used backticks like `` `echo "$i" | sed -E s/pattern/replacement/` `` for command substitution - they're deprecated now, although still supported.) Note the use of double quotes, without which the command will break on filenames that contain whitespace or other shell-special characters.

On current Ubuntu systems, there should be a Perl-based `rename` command that **can** operate on the dirents directly:

```
rename 's/pattern/replacement/' *.mp3
```

where `pattern` is a Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE). There's also an `mmv` command (provided by an Ubuntu package of the same name) that works with shell globs instead of regular expressions and is often easier for simple re-arrangments like this ex.:

```
mmv '*. * - *.mp3' '#3 - #2.mp3'
```

Both `rename` and `mmv` have a `-n` option that lets you trial-run the re-namings.

Comment: I finished all my file renames using mostly the rename command, and then the mv command when rename failed. Rename is a very powerful tool!

Comment: and rename is also supported with gui approach using krusader file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mmv`. In your case:

```
mmv '[0-9][0-9][0-9]. * - *.mp3' '#5 - #4.mp3'
```

`mmv` uses `#1` for the first wildcard match, `#2` for the second etc.; in this pattern we have three wildcards for the leading digits, then a literal dot, a literal blank, then the song artist (#4) and the song title (#5) separated by " - ".

In the replacement part, we omit the unwanted numbers and swap artist and title.

Life can be so simple when you use the right tools. ;-)

`mmv` is a marvel. Read the man page and experiment; you will find it well worth-while.

You may have to install the package: `sudo apt install mmv`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use a tool like `kid3-qt` that can read ID3 tags from MP3s and create your own rule how to rename the files based on several different tags to choose from. It can rename a whole directory worth of MP3 files at once.